# check if user has a valid recurring profile

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Im trying to build an opencart extension where a product is a subscription and the user must renew it every month. So once he purchase the subscription, the user will have the ability to download certain documents from the product page.

What i need to do is check if the user has a valid active recurring profile then show the download links or if the subscription is expired or inactive hide the links.

Can someone guide me on how to do this?

Im using opencart 2.3.

Comment: You can create a DB table for product_subscription containing customer_id,product_id,subscription_started,renewal_counts.

From all above information you can check and provide links and can notify user for renewal of their products.

Comment: I think there is an extension already available for `subscription` model. Maybe try the demo so you may get more info on how to `start`. 
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=9890